# Error: "the multi-part could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about the error: "the multi-part could not be bound". Looked it up and told me to do what I did in the first Insert INTO Value, but it gave me a syntax error. What should I do to fix this? I left the code and a picture below.

```
CREATE DATABASE [dbo]. [tCostumes](
[CostumeID] [int],
[Characters] [nchar] (50),
[Price] [int],
[DateNeeded] [nchar] (60)

CREATE SEQUENCE orderNumber
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 0
maxvalue 100
cycle;

INSERT INTO tCostume 
VALUES ((CostumeID = orderNumber.nextval), ‘Okabe’, 30, ‘Oct 31 2020’); 



INSERT INTO tCostume 
VALUES (orderNumber.nextval, ‘Batman’, 20, ‘Oct 30 2020’);

INSERT INTO tCostume 
VALUES (orderNumber.nextval, ‘Accelerator’, 75, May 24 2021’);`
```

[image: Some Image]

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR orderNumber` https://sqlhints.com/tag/sql-sequence-in-insert-statement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @Fuzzy that using an identity column makes more sense, and that it appears that you're actually trying to create a table, not a database; here is a working version of the sample code you posted (HT to @shawnt00 for pointing out the correct syntax for the sequence)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[tCostumes];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tCostumes] (
[CostumeID] [int],
[Characters] [nchar] (50),
[Price] [int],
[DateNeeded] [nchar] (60))

CREATE SEQUENCE orderNumber
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 0
maxvalue 100
cycle;

INSERT INTO tCostumes
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR orderNumber, 'Okabe', 30, 'Oct 31 2020'); 



INSERT INTO tCostumes
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR orderNumber, 'Batman', 20, 'Oct 30 2020');

INSERT INTO tCostumes
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR orderNumber, 'Accelerator', 75, 'May 24 2021');

SELECT * FROM tCostumes
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an IDENTITY specification on the ID column?
You also probably want to create a table instead of a database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo]. [tCostumes](
[CostumeID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Characters] [nchar] (50),
[Price] [int],
[DateNeeded] [nchar] (60))

INSERT INTO tCostumes (Characters, Price, DateNeeded)
VALUES ('Okabe', 30, 'Oct 31 2020')
```

Alternatively if you really want to use a sequence, this might work:

```
INSERT INTO tCostumes (Characters, Price, DateNeeded)
VALUES ((SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR orderNumber), 'Okabe', 30, 'Oct 31 2020');
```

Source: [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Edit: While I was editting my answer @DavidP suggested the same solution for using the sequence and provided a complete code sample.